# Calling subdir.mk from Makefile with multiple code directories

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Below is the folder structure for my code.
This is a very small example to understand the concept of multiple makefiles based on which I have to create makefile for bigger code structure.

```
work
├── code
|     | 
|     └── main.h and test.h files here
│     └── main.c and test.c files here
|     └── subdir.mk
|
├── _Build/
│     └── Makefile here
```

I am keeping both Makefile and subdir.mk files to be very basic and simple to grasp the concept.

Below is the code for subdir.mk

```
#subdir.mk
#============================================
test.o : test.c test.h
    @echo Building test.c ...
    gcc -Werror -Wall -c test.c -o test.o

main.o : main.c main.h test.h
    @echo Building main.c ...
    gcc -Werror -Wall -c main.c -o main.o
#============================================
```

Below is the code for main file ... Makefile

```
#Makefile
#============================================

include ../code/subdir.mk

main : ../code/main.o ..code/test.o
    @echo Building ...

    make subdir.mk # <--- What is the correct way to perform this code

    @echo Linking files ...
    gcc -Llib ../code/main.o ../code/test.o -lm -o main

clean:
    rm -rv ../code/*.o
#============================================
```

The error I am getting is

```
make: *** No rule to make target 'test.c', needed by 'test.o'.  Stop.
```

In subdir.mk I am trying to generate object files.
In Makefile I am trying to link the object files generated in subdir.mk

The way I am trying to execute is correct way or some different steps are followed when we have multiple subdir.mk and main Makefile.

Share your valuable comments please.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot both include the `subdir.mk` file and also invoke it recursively.

You need to decide whether you want to use non-recursive make (which means you'd use include) or recursive make (which means you'd run a sub-make command).

If you want to use non-recursive make then your `subdir.mk` makefile needs to be prepared to be run when the current working directory is different than the directory that the subdir.mk file appears in.

If you want to use recursive make then you need a separate rule to build the objects, and you should *not* `include subdirs.mk`.  Something like this:

```
main : ../code/main.o ..code/test.o
        @echo Linking files ...
        gcc -Llib ../code/main.o ../code/test.o -lm -o main

../code/main.o ..code/test.o : subdir ;

subdir:
        @echo Building ...
        cd ../code && $(MAKE) -f subdir.mk
.PHONY: subdir
```

Be sure to include the semicolon after the `subdir` in the `.o` rule.
When invoking sub-makes you should *always* use the `$(MAKE)` variable, never use the literal string `make`.

You will probably be better off having your `subdir.mk` build a single library out of the objects rather than having to repeat all the object files in multiple places.  Then replace the list of object files in this makefile with the library.

Contrary to Andreas's assertion, this will not always rebuild `main`.  It will only be rebuilt when one of the object files was changed.

Comment: For recursive I got a good idea from yours and Andreas's kind comments. For non-recursive what changes I have to made and which file needs to be modified? Also which method is preferred recursive or non-recursive? Need your valuable comments on this. Thanks

Comment: With your code, error is coming `gcc.exe: error: ../code/main.o: No such file or directory`. Am I missing something? After entering subdir.mk, only test.c is getting compiled.

Comment: Ah, right. Did not consider the possibility of duplicating the dependencies declared in `subdir.mk` in the top Makefile. Much too lazy for that extra maintenance :)

Comment: In general people prefer non-recursive makefiles for any moderately complex system, because once the environment is set up it's easier to use.  However defining it in the first place is harder. Non-recursive is fine for simpler situations.  In order to make it work you need to prefix all the targets with appropriate paths.  What "appropriate" means depends on what kind of setup you want.  If you always want to build from the same directory then using hardcoded paths works, if unpleasant.  Alternatively you can set a variable to the path you want and use the variable.

Answer (score 1):

`subdir.mk` has to use paths relative to the main makefile.  E.g.

```
../code/test.o : ../code/test.c ../code/test.h
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a recipe for creating the object files. In Makefile you'll need to remove `include ../code/subdir.mk` and add something like this:

```
.PHONY: ../code/main.o ..code/test.o
../code/main.o ..code/test.o:
    $(MAKE) -C ../code/ -f subdir.mk $(@F)
```

When you build target `main`, make sees you need the object files. Then make find the above recipe for creating the object files and so runs it.

Having them `.PHONY` is because the top Makefile can´t tell whether or not they´re up to date. Without it the object files would never be rebuilt. This has the unfortunate consequence that `main` will always be rebuilt, even if `subdir.mk` determines the object files were indeed up to date. The solution is either to have it all in a single make (can still split into files and include), or change to a build tool that can get it right.

Comment: when I am using `include ../code/subdir.mk` in Makefile I am getting the same error `'make: *** No rule to make target 'test.c', needed by 'test.o'.  Stop.`. Reason for the error is not known. Including the subdir.mk in Makefile is wrong?

Comment: Right, you should also remove `include ../code/subdir.mk`. Update coming right up.

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. For non-recursive what changes are needed?

Comment: You'd have to 1) rewrite `subdir.mk` so that all paths (files) are relative top Makefile (e.g. test.o -> ../code/test.o), and 2) have the top Makefile include `subdir.mk`. See @ensc answer.

Comment: Could you please guide more. I have changed subdir.mk with relative path and removed `$(MAKE) -C ../code/ -f subdir.mk $(@F)` from Makefile. The result I am getting is only `test.o` is created. No command execution for `main.o`. Also in Makefile linking command is also not executed.

Comment: You should open new questions for new issues. Good luck!