# Makefile non-recursive method issues

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am trying to build using Makefile below code structure using non-recursive method as per the guidance I received in

[link description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63941725/calling-subdir-mk-from-makefile-with-multiple-code-directories/63943455?noredirect=1#comment113087976_63943455)

```
work
├── code
|     | 
|     └── main.h and test.h files here
│     └── main.c and test.c files here
|     └── subdir.mk
|
├── _Build/
│     └── Makefile here
```

Below is the Makefile

```
-include ../code/subdir.mk

all : target_file

target_file : ../code/main.o ../code/test.o
    @echo Building ...
    @echo Linking files ...
    gcc -Llib ../code/main.o ../code/test.o -lm -o target_file  

clean:
    rm -rv ../code/*.o
```

Below is the subdir.mk file

```
../code/test.o : ../code/test.c ../code/test.h
    @echo Building test.c ...
    gcc -Werror -Wall -c ../code/test.c -o ../code/test.o

../code/main.o : ../code/main.c ../code/main.h ../code/test.h
    @echo Building main.c ...
    gcc -Werror -Wall -c ../code/main.c -o ../code/main.o
```

The output I am getting while running make command is below

```
Building test.c ...
gcc -Werror -Wall -c ../code/test.c -o ../code/test.o
```

There is no error I am getting nor main.o is getting generated. Also in Makefile the linking command is not executed.

Answer (score 1):

That's likely because `make` by default builds the *first* target it encounters. Since you include the `subdir.mk` before your `all : target_file` line, the first target named in `subdir.mk` is built, and nothing else. Solution: place the `subdir.mk` inclusion last, e.g. near the end.